# How to use state from a component 's reducer to another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, state

Here is my project structure

```
src
 - Module1
     -action
     -components
     -reducer
- Module2
     -action
     -components
     -reducer
```

Can I use Modules1's reducer state in Module2's components without writing the whole process again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. the connect function allow you to use all modules' state or action, if your redux config correctly.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  state1: state.module1.state1,
  state2: state.module2.state2,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  action1: dispatch.module1.action1,
  action2: dispatch.module2.action2,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(component);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how do I get another module's instance to connect with its states?

Comment: `mapStateToProps` function will add redux state(global state) to the component's `props`. To access the state you can use `this.props.state1` or `this.props.state2` from @shen 's example above.